# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to configure react router but got this strange error

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string.. check
>   render method of Main.

I have my Main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
      </h1>
      {React.createElement(props.children, props)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

This is my index.js

```
import Main from './components/Main'
import Single from './components/Single'
import PhotoGrid from './components/PhotoGrid'

//routes
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

const router = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>   
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I think it might cause by react-router, I don't know. If I simply do

```
render(<Main>hi</Main>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I can see it working. Strange.

Comment: The way you use `React.createElement` is incorrect. See here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement first argument should be a string or react component

Answer (score 0):

In your `return` of `main.js` you can just use `{props.children}` no need for `React.createElement`.

```
const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
      </h1>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**EDIT**:
A followup to your comment, if you want to pass props via the route:

```
const router = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main} myProp={"this is a prop!"}>
      <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>   
    </Route>
  </Router>
)
```

And then pull it from the `route`:

```
const Main = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        <Link to="/">Reduxstagram</Link>
      </h1>
      {props.route.myProp}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: but how does the props of children goes into its children? Main has other components as well.

Comment: the router can pass them